# Изменение ширины элемента в зависимости от текста в нем

Tags: html, css, html5, jade

На картинке видно, что символы в первой и последной строчке не совсем помещаются в элементы (li) списка (ul).
А вот хотелось бы, чтобы всё помещалось и центрировалось.
Инлайн-блок не помогает.
Синим я подцветил тег li, в котором находится список.

[image: http://dl4.joxi.net/drive/2016/12/30/0001/0403/94611/11/0b627d44fc.png]

Разметка (Jade):

```
ul
    li(data-text="GALLERY") GALLERY
    li(data-text="BLOG") BLOG
    li(data-text="ABOUT") ABOUT
```

Но она особо ни о чем не говорит.

Padding для этой цели изменить нельзя, нужно обойтись другим способом.
Помогите, пожалуйста.
Совсем не понимаю, почему в теге может обрезаться шрифт и не помещаться в него...

Comment: А почему `inline-block` не подошёл?

Comment: А по той причине, что он просто не работает никак.
Выше по разметке идет работа с флекс-контейнерами, и даже inline-flex не помогает.
Дело конкретно в таком шрифте...  Кстати, это Sansita One с гугл фонтс.

Comment: overflow: visible также не работает.

Comment: На последней строчке можно заметить, что "А" обрезана тоже.
То есть строка в li центрировалась, а ширина осталась равна... Не знаю даже чему. Сумме ширины всех символов шрифта?

Comment: Это из за самого шрифта. Когда его рисовали, неправильно составили скелет

Comment: @Yuri, да вполне возможно. Я не нашел в сети как через css управлять шириной символа шрифта.

Comment: @VostokSisters Я до сих пор не понимаю почему нельзя было создать минимальный, адекватный и воспроизводимый пример. Вы можете добавить запускаемый пример со шрифтом, с которым у вас затруднения?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пришлось использовать всё-таки padding для этой цели.
А в after прописать padding: 0 inherit.
Работает как и должно, текст фиксированный.
Результат: [тык](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2016/12/30/0001/0403/94611/11/ee241e38be.png)

Comment: А можете добавить сюда код?

Comment: За нежелание добавлять код сюда, полезность этого ответа равна нулю. Добавите рабочий код с объяснением, почему выбрано именно такое решение — уберу минус.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй добавить к `li` следующие стили:

```
li:before, li:after {
   display: inline-block;
   content: '';
   width: 8px; /* Тут надо самому свою внести */
   height: 10px; /* Тут высоту свою указать */
}
```

А вообще, мой совет: поменяй шрифт, так как мой способ - это костыль

Comment: Не смогу, посколько after уже используется для создания градиентрого текста.

Comment: @VostokSisters, а зачем? Можно же цвет сделать градиентным без дополнительных блоков

Comment: @VostokSisters, http://shpargalkablog.ru/2013/11/gradient-text.html

Comment: Градиентным можно, но не получится, используя один элемент сделать его градиентным и с тенью позади одновременно)
[без синих блоков](http://dl3.joxi.net/drive/2016/12/30/0001/0403/94611/11/f058e162e7.png)
Можно использовать filter: drop-shadow(), но так как используется анимация появления этой менюшки, это не выход, потому что на даже на хроме уже немного заметны лаги, а фаерфокс отвратительно отрисовывает эту тень.

Comment: невозможно по той причине, что text-shadow отрисовывается перед градиентом.
Увы. Так тупо сделали.

Comment: @VostokSisters, тогда можно через js исправлять или вручную вводить

Comment: да можно убрать ли и всё в суп из дивов засунуть, тогда проблем вообще не будет, я смогу управлять шириной дивов как угодно.
И без костылей на js.
Но я не хочу. Я хочу, чтобы работало не на костылях.

Comment: @VostokSisters, увы, я вариантов больше не вижу